# Swapping first and last digit in an integer using bitwise operator

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have been asked in an interview to swap the last and first digit in an integer using bitwise operators. Tried a lot but I could not find the solution. How can I do this?

Comment: What wrong with this question

Comment: Liberal use of `% 10` will get you where you need to go.  As for "what's wrong", most SO users prefer you to show an attempt to solve it, and ask about where you're getting stuck.

Comment: What kind of "number?" int? float? Represented as a string?

Comment: ITS simply an integer...

Comment: And i have to do it using bitwise operator

Comment: @Amit Singh Tomar: Please edit the question to be precise and add in what you attempted to do and where you became stuck.

Answer (score 7):

Use `int digits = log10(x)` to get the number of digits.

Use `int first = x / pow(10,digits)` to get the first digit.

Use `int last = x % 10` to get the last digit.

Put it all together and you have

`int swapped = x + (last - first) * pow(10,digits) + (first - last)`

Comment: Fails for 999999999999999 on my system.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: Yes, because `999999999999999 > 2^31-1` is too large for an `int`. I was assuming (perhaps poorly, but based on the comments to the question) that `x` is given as an `int`.

Comment: Nice!  But I think `int first = x % pow(10,digits)` should be `/` instead of `%`.

Answer (score 4):

A trivial solution:

```
def swap_digit(n):
    x = str(n)
    if len(x) < 2:
        return x
    return  int(x[-1] + x[1:-1] + x[0])
```

EDIT: Added a quick and dirty C solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 123456789;

    char buf[100];
    int r = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", n);
    char t = buf[0];
    buf[0] = buf[r-1];
    buf[r-1] = t;
    int swap;
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &swap);

    printf("n = %d,  swap = %d\n", n, swap);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Mikola have u take number as string??

Comment: Doesn't matter, but it returns an integer.  You could easily modify it to do something else though.

Comment: @Mikola but there's a `C` tag on this question.

Comment: @Deepak:  Fair enough, added a C version too.

Comment: `strtol` would be better, no?

Comment: @Chris Lutz:  Probably.  This is a pretty dirty piece of code, I am more posting it since Deepak asked, not because there is really any insight or value intrinsic value in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def swap(i):
    s = list(str(i))
    s[0], s[-1] = s[-1], s[0]
    i = int(''.join(s))
    return i

print swap(123456789) # 923456781
```